# why isn't my button on sync with my onclick event?

Tags: javascript, events

I was learning javascript and came across a video about using onclick events,(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQEfWd1lh4Q&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9i9Ae2D9Ee1RvylH38dKuET&index=41&t=23s).Basically, the guy made a card that could expand to show the part of the content that it cut off. I was able to follow along and only somewhat understand by watching the video. So to deepen my understanding I decided to recode what was shown in the video without referring back to it.

I kinda got what I wanted, but there's one small thing that's been getting me frustrated. When I run my code, I get my condensed card with the button that says "Show More" (which is good"), but when I press the button, the card expands but the button still says "Show More" (which is where it starts getting bad), and only when I press the button a third time to condense the card does the button read "Show Less".

```js
var contentDiv = document.querySelector('.content');
var button = document.querySelector('.button');

button.onclick = function(){
  if(contentDiv.className == 'content'){
    contentDiv.classList.add('appear');
    button.innerHTML = 'Show More';
  } else if(contentDiv.className == 'content appear'){
    contentDiv.classList.remove('appear');
    button.innerHTML = 'Show Less';
  }
};
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  background: #a1a1a1;
}

.group{
  margin-top: 10%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.content{
  background: #dedede;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #2e2e2e;
  background: #e8e8e8;

  transition: all .5s;
}

.appear{
  height: 530px;
  color: #e8e8e8;
  background: #2e2e2e;
}

.content p{
  margin: 10px;
}

.button{
  margin: 10px;
  background: #f0ca62;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Events</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="group">
      <div class="content">
        <p>width inflation scrape lamp continuation insistence proof pioneer trait
          vegetation dorm bring ball charter joy brick cabinet nest use economist
          width inflation scrape lamp continuation insistence proof pioneer trait
          vegetation dorm bring ball charter joy brick cabinet nest use economist
          width inflation scrape lamp continuation insistence proof pioneer trait
          vegetation dorm bring ball charter joy brick cabinet nest use economist
        </p>
        <p>width inflation scrape lamp continuation insistence proof pioneer trait
          vegetation dorm bring ball charter joy brick cabinet nest use economist
          width inflation scrape lamp continuation insistence proof pioneer trait
          vegetation dorm bring ball charter joy brick cabinet nest use economist
        </p>
        <p>width inflation scrape lamp continuation insistence proof pioneer trait
          vegetation dorm bring ball charter joy brick cabinet nest use economist
        </p>
      </div>

      <a class="button">Show More</a>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[link to code in codepen](https://codepen.io/joppy/pen/Yzzvzrq)

Comment: Your code is set to change the button's text to `Show More` when the `div.content` has only the class `content` and to `Show Less` when it has the classes `content appear`. To switch that, switch the `if` statements conditions or the text you set `button.innerHTML` to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the show more and show less buttons are reversed, try this:

```
button.onclick = function(){
  if(contentDiv.className == 'content'){
    contentDiv.classList.add('appear');
    button.innerHTML = 'Show Less';
  } else if(contentDiv.className == 'content appear'){
    contentDiv.classList.remove('appear');
    button.innerHTML = 'Show More';
  }
};
```